# How to divide a sentence into parts Java?

Tags: java, string, sentence

How can I divide a sentence like `"He and his brother playing football."` into few part like `"He and"`, `"and his"`, `"his brother"`, `"brother playing"` and `"playing football"` . Is it possible to do that by using Java?

Comment: While we're at it, what do you specifically mean by dividing a sentence into (a) "few part"? What parts?

Comment: The magic word is delimiters!

Comment: I have try using delimiters. But I cant make it to divide the sentence as above.

Comment: I mean I want to divide the sentence in to words as shown above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the "words" are always separated by a single space. Use `String.split()`

```
String[] words = "He and his brother playing football.".split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0, l = words.length; i + 1 < l; i++)
        System.out.println(words[i] + " " + words[i + 1]);
```

Comment: thank you is works. And I have 1 more problem can I divide the sentences into "He", "He and","and his", "his brother", "brother playing" and "playing football". I want to get the first word then follow by other.

Comment: @cchua, So, just get `words[0]` before the loop.

Comment: @cchua, Assuming you mean, the last letter of the last word. `String s = words[words.length-1]; s.charAt(s.length() - 1)`....Do you have more specific rules? Should they be special characters? I'm sorry, but your requirements seem vague.

Comment: Is just need to include all the Punctuation occur in the sentences. For example ", . ? ! "

Comment: @cchua, There are regular expression that can help. I think a example will help. Edit your question and give me an exact example of what you need.

Comment: The question is same as above "He and his brother playing football." into few part like "He", "He and", "and his", "his brother", "brother playing", "playing football", "football." and ".".

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using **BreakIterator class** and its **static method getSentenceInstance().**
 It `Returns a new BreakIterator instance for sentence breaks for the default locale`.

`You can also use getWordInstance(), getLineInstance().. to break words, line...etc`

eg:

```
BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance();

boundary.setText("Your_Sentence");

int start = boundary.first();

int end = boundary.next();
```

`Iterate over it... to get the Sentences....`

For more detail look at this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html

**Edited Answer**: `This is a working code`

```
String sent = "My name is vivek. I work in TaxSmart";
        BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance();
        bi.setText(sent);
        int index = 0;
        while (bi.next() != BreakIterator.DONE) {
        String sentence = sent.substring(index, bi.current());
        System.out.println("Sentence: " + sentence);
        index = bi.current();
        }
```

Comment: I don't get it can you give me a full example to run it.

Comment: Interesting, first time hear about this `BreakIterator` class. I just tested, the result contains whitespaces. for example, for `how are you?`, i got `0,3[how] 3,4[ ] 4,7[are] 7,8[ ] 8,11[you] 11,12[?]`

Answer (score 3):

```
String str="He and his brother playing football";

    String [] strArray=str.split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<strArray.length-1 ;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(strArray[i]+" "+strArray[i+1]);
    }
```

Comment: thank you is works. And I have 1 more problem can I divide the sentences into "He", "He and","and his", "his brother", "brother playing", "playing football" and "football.".

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringTokenizer to separate by spaces or other characters.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Test {

         private static String[] tokenize(String str) {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str);
        String[] arr = new String[tokenizer.countTokens()];
        int i = 0;
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        arr[i++] = tokenizer.nextToken();
        }
        return arr;
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strs = tokenize("Sandy sells seashells by the sea shore.");
        for (String s : strs)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Should print out:

Sandy

sells

seashells

by

the

sea

shore.

May or may not be what you're after.

Comment: I don't get it can you give me a full example to run it.

Comment: @cchua Try that. It will divide by _spaces_ though, not like in speech. What are you trying to do with it anyway?

Comment: The thing is I need to divide it into 2 words as above. Later I will think a way to make a comparison with 2 words that is stated in a text file. Inside the text file contain many lines of sentences.