# String split at second occurance of space using java

Tags: java, regex

Split String based on second occurance of space.
Eg)
string like A B C D E

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {

        String s="A B C D E";
        String[] spl=s.split("(?<=\\s\\S{1,100})\\s");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(spl));
        for(int i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(spl[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

the above code gives

```
[A B, C, D, E]
A B
C
D
E
```

What I want the get is the below format:

```
[A B, C D, E]
A B
C D
E
```

Comment: Not an elegant solution, but you can always split by space, then "join" the result's entries in a new array, in pairs.

Comment: thanks for your response

Comment: i got some idea from here  ..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095096/how-to-divide-a-sentence-into-parts-java

Comment: Check the answer by @azro, it's a great solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find a way to split following your requirement is as nt as easy, I would propose a way with `matching groups` instead

```
String s = "A B C D E";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w\\s\\w)|\\w");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()){
        res.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(res);          //    [A B, C D, E]
```

[***Workable Demo***](https://ideone.com/TkDIx0)